# access specific key of interface with parameter of function

Tags: typescript

basically speaking i have two interfaces:

```
interface config {
    lang: "en" | "de";
    test: number;
}

interface Accessor {
    key ( k: keyof config ): config[k];
}
```

and i want to dynamically have the type of whatever i access from the `config` type, via the Accessor object. is that possible?

*note: my code is a lot more complicated and i cannot just access the keys directly, but it boils down to this in the end*

Comment: That `k` is a parameter name, not a type.  Instead you want `key` to be generic in the type of `k`.    Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKq1KN).  Does that meet your needs and I can write up an answer?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: thank you yes that solves my problem. can you quickly explain to me how / why it works like that?

Comment: I can write up an answer explaining it, but "quickly" isn't something I can commit to

Comment: oh okay, well i don't need it quickly, i just don't want to bother you that much. is there at least a place in the documentation where i can find more information? thank you anyways for your help!

Comment: i may have misread your first comment and read "Does that meet your needs **or do I need to** write up an answer", instead of "Does that meet your needs **and I can** write up an answer". sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key()` method signature in your `Accessor` interface should return an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) of the form `Config[X]` where `X` is the type of the `k` parameter.  Your attempt, `Config[k]`, is not valid, because `k` is the *value* of the parameter; you need its *type*.   This can be remedied using [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) like so:

```
interface Accessor {
    key(k: keyof Config): Config[typeof k];
}
```

This now compiles with no error.  And you can even use it:

```
declare const a: Accessor;
const langProp = a.key("lang");
// const langProp: number | "en" | "de" 
const testProp = a.key("test");
// const testProp: number | "en" | "de"
```

But as you can see, the behavior is not really what you want.  The type of `result` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of possible property types of `Config`. In fact, the `key()` call signature returns the same type no matter what the input is.  The type of `k` is just `keyof Config`.  And `keyof Config` is the union `"lang" | "test"`. And `Config[typeof k]` is `Config[keyof Config]` is `Config["lang" | "test"]` is `Config["lang"] | Config["test"]` is `"en" | "de" | number`.  There's nothing about the call signature which pays attention to *which* key is being passed in.

---

What you want is for `a.key("lang")` to return `"en" | "de"` and for `a.key("test")` to return `number`.  That implies you want `key()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `k`.  That is, instead of `k` being of type `keyof Config`, it should be of a generic type, let's call it `K`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof Config`:

```
interface Accessor {
    key<K extends keyof Config>(k: K): Config[typeof k];
}
```

Here `K` is a *generic type parameter*, declared inside angle brackets after the name of the method but before the opening parenthesis for the function parameter list.  Once it is so declared, we can refer to `K` as a type elsewhere in the call signature.

And once we do that, everything works as desired:

```
declare const a: Accessor;
const langProp = a.key("lang");
// const langProp: "en" | "de" 
const testProp = a.key("test");
// const testProp: number
```

---

Note that the `typeof` type operator isn't really necessary if you already have a name for the type.  In our case, `k` is of type `K`, so `typeof k` can just be written as `K`:

```
interface Accessor {
    key<K extends keyof Config>(k: K): Config[K];
}
```

And everything still works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&noErrorTruncation=true#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAwge3PUBzNAb2DTLQBtFx8AuNAImnAbQB9GATaBgblPIwAzpHrgArgFsARnH4BfEOESToQgA4p0AQUgxJ6yAEZiAshBgItabclRChWWKfKu0Aa2gBPABTv6nl5Y8Jg4ePgAlPTYuAQA2pBe6tDBHgC6-K6KrtzIVLDoyDgiaIj0tvaOsJnkReAlVDQACrBY6mgAvKUAdIE+DI34DBE1ZAD0Y2h1DdT4LW1iUrLOHEws7Fw8ZlPFkGjCkPPtXYi93v0Hw6NoEzv1ewdHizJwG2usq9wMIMCKyqoaay6fSGABMLnIFjgSFQNjsaiqELcHm8AB4ANJoaAADxg4E4QhRQRCMXCAD4-PR0VFQrF8AkkikQu4MttFNtcvlCrtSuV4Q4nNdpntBkdOj0+gNZldtrdhZRZk9GMwPptvq55Y9WscJecGJcRrLJpq1Idtc9liB2cB-mpNLCAGIQRAUJFoKFWWEVBFON2uQIYrG45gEompUkECn+NDU6JheLo1lZEA5aB5RAFO4lMpwyqC7by0Xa8WnSWDGWuOU8osLZXrT5bDU8rVtEtnXz600V8hV+77U1KiQvWBWkBAA)

Comment: that is so detailed and understandable, thank you so much for this!